# Cloud task doesn't run on time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

What I am trying to do is to change the data in firestore using cloud function and cloud task on a scheduled time. But cloud task doesn't run on time. It is executed right after adding task.

My code is like this.

`index.js`

```
exports.addTasks = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const client = new tasks.CloudTasksClient()

  const projectId = ...
  const queue = ...
  const location = ...

  const parent = client.queuePath(projectId, location, queue)

  const url = ... .cloudfunctions.net/doSomething?docId=' + docId

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: url,
      scheduleTime: {
        seconds: 3 * 60 + Date.now() / 1000,
      }, 
    }
  }

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  }

  client.createTask(request)
})

exports.doSomething = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  var db = admin.firestore()
  var docId = req.query.docId
  var docRef = db.collection('people').doc(docId)

  docRef.update({
    changeHere: true,
  })
})
```

I want to run `doSomething` function 3 minutes after `addTasks` is executed.  What am I wrong with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scheduleTime` is a property of the task object and not a property of `httpRequest`.

```
  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: url,
    },
    scheduleTime: {
      seconds: 3 * 60 + Date.now() / 1000,
    }, 
  }
```

Here is the [reference doc](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/tasks/latest/google.cloud.tasks.v2.html#.Task) and [sample code](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-tasks/blob/master/samples/createHttpTask.js#L63) showing this.